# Height not stretching to 100%

Tags: html, css

My span height (class="figure") is not stretching to 100% height of the list item

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
       <li>
           <span class="stepLabel">Step</span>
           <span class="figure"></span>
           <img src="indent.png" alt="ghost" class="ghost">
       </li>
       <li>
           <span class="stepLabel">Step</span>
           <span class="figure"></span>
           <img src="indent.png" alt="ghost" class="ghost">
       </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container { width: 90%; margin: 10px auto; border: 1px solid #d8d8d8; }
ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
ul li { display: block; width: 12.1%; height: auto; float: left; margin-left: -1%; }
ul li .stepLabel { display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 999; }
ul li img.ghost { width: 100%; height: auto; position: relative; z-index: 1; opacity: 0.1; }

.figure { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6YsT3/

Comment: I haven't seen this before but if you made it, it's very creative

Comment: not the way i would like to do things but unfortunately i have to

Comment: if you mean the span stretching to push the text up, you don't have to.  Arantir's answer will prevent this.  If you mean the fact that it's a staircase made out of an unordered list, then i think it's awesome and original.

Answer (score 2):

`width`/`heigh` 100%?
You can use `position: absolute` and `left`/`right`/`top`/`bottom` `0`-s

http://jsfiddle.net/6YsT3/5/

Don't forget parent's `position: relative` (for `li`);

Answer (score 2):

Set the height of the parent `li`.

```
ul li {
    height: 72px;
}
```

The initial height of an element is `auto`, therefore that isn't even doing anything. The `span` element will collapse upon itself, as `100%` of auto is actually just `0`.

[**Updated jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/6YsT3/4/)

Comment: it has to be auto though for responsive design

Comment: the LI height changes based on the image inside of it, i need the figure span to expand as well, maybe i have to nest the image inside of that span

Comment: @JMcFee then set the li to position: relative and the contents to position: absolute with top and left attribs with percents.

Comment: maybe i m just understanding wrong... make your <li class="figure">

Comment: I'm on mobile, so I wasn't gonna post a whole code answer. I saw @Arantir gave the same idea with an answer after I wrote my comment. :)